# How to solve Output argument when it's not assigned into program for sub function

Tags: matlab

The drinking water standard for iron is 0.3mg/L. Similarly, the standard for magnesium is 0.05mg/L. Create a program that will take in the measured values of iron and magnesium and display whether the water is safe to drink.

I have started the program that is testing Iron first and then will create another program testing for Magnesium. My issue is that I have to use sub-functions to solve the program and I get the correct answer however an error follows in the command window. I know that it has to involve `test=testWater(IronSafe)` because I haven't declared my output statement and I'm not sure how to implement it into my code.

```
function [IronStand] = ProblemWATER(IronSafe)
%Create a function that states whether H20 for iron is safe to drink
% 1 inputs: IronSafe
% 1 output:IronStand 
IronSafe = input('What is the density level of your iron \n');
IronStand = testWater(IronSafe);
end
function test= testWater(IronSafe)
%Subfunction meant to determine if IronStand drinkable
IronStand = 0.3;
if IronSafe == IronStand
    disp('Safe to drink'); 
else 
    disp('Not safe');
end
end
```

My Command Window displays:
[image]

Comment: If you want to test the water for safety, it needs to have *at most* 0.3mg/L, not *exactly* 0.3mg/L, which is what you are testing. Change `==` to `<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your second function `function test= testWater(IronSafe)`. You are returning the value `test` but never assigning it to anything. You can solve it by removing it:

```
function [] = ProblemWATER(IronSafe)
%Create a function that states whether H20 for iron is safe to drink
% 1 inputs: IronSafe
% 1 output:IronStand 
IronSafe = input('What is the density level of your iron \n');
testWater(IronSafe);
end

function [] = testWater(IronSafe)
%Subfunction meant to determine if IronStand drinkable
IronStand = 0.3;
if IronSafe == IronStand
    disp('Safe to drink'); 
else 
    disp('Not safe');
end
end
```

If you want the value of `IronStand` back then you need to change the return value:

```
function [IronStand] = ProblemWATER(IronSafe)
%Create a function that states whether H20 for iron is safe to drink
% 1 inputs: IronSafe
% 1 output:IronStand 
IronSafe = input('What is the density level of your iron \n');
IronStand = testWater(IronSafe);
end

function [IronStand] = testWater(IronSafe)
%Subfunction meant to determine if IronStand drinkable
IronStand = 0.3;
if IronSafe == IronStand
    disp('Safe to drink'); 
else 
    disp('Not safe');
end
end
```

Comment: I have attempted that however I get another error saying I have too many output arguments and an error in line 6.

Comment: It is caused by `IronStand = testWater(IronSafe);` requesting a return value. See the edit for more explanation

Comment: ok I understand now; that makes sense. Thank you I really appreciate it (: